# Child route is not reached

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following routing structure

```
{
        path: 'patients',
        children: [
          { path: '', component: PatientsComponent },
          {
            path: ':id', component: PatientComponent, children: [
              {
                path: 'sessions',
                children: [
                  { path: ':id', component: SessionComponent },
                  { path: '', component: SessionsComponent }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
```

I can access `/patients` and `/patients/:id` but i cannot reach `/patients/:id/sessions` or `/patients/:id/sessions/:id`

Any reason why?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at this article: https://vsavkin.com/the-powerful-url-matching-engine-of-angular-router-775dad593b03

Comment: Add both components templates

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a new `<router-outlet>` for every `children` array? If you're only using a single `<router-outlet>` the following definition would suffice:

```
  { path: 'patients', component: PatientsComponent },
  { path: 'patients/:id', component: PatientComponent },
  { path: 'patients/:id/sessions', component: SessionsComponent},
  { path: 'patients/:id/sessions/:sessionid', component: SessionComponent},
```

Check out the docs on [child-route-configuration](https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration). Important quote:

> There are important differences in the way the router treats these child routes. The router displays the components of these routes in the RouterOutlet of the CrisisCenterComponent, not in the RouterOutlet of the AppComponent shell.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, while it solves my problem, it doesn't really explain why.

Comment: Read the child-route-configuration docs I've linked. If you add `children` array to your route definition you need to add corresponsing `<router-outlet>` in that component template. But for basic navigation there is no need for nested `<router-outlet>` and you can use a single `<router-outlet>` in app.component with the route definition I posted above.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou can you explain what you are having a problem with?